# MySQL SubQuery - MySQL 3.23

Tags: mysql, subquery

I've 2 tables, emp_master and passport_details.

```
emp_master(emp_id,first_name,email_id,dob,doj,status.........)
passport_details(id, emp_id,passport_number,given_name,......).
```

I am trying to fetch emp_id and first_name from emp_master who have not entered passport_details.

I tried different combination of SubQueries, used    NOT IN, NOT EXISTS.

```
SELECT emp_id,first_name
FROM emp_master
WHERE emp_id NOT IN(SELECT emp_id FROM passport_details WHERE status=1);
```

I am getting error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'SELECT emp_id FROM passport_details WHERE status=1)' at line 3
```

**I am using MySQL 3.23.**

My question is

> 1. Do MySQL 3.23 supports SubQueries?
> 2. What could be the optimal query to fetch emp_id and first_name from emp_master who have not entered passport_details.

Comment: Subqueries were added in 4.1 IIRC

Comment: Bingo - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-nutshell.html

Answer (score 5):

```
select em.emp_id, em.first_name
from emp_master em left join passport_details pd
    on pd.emp_id = em.emp_id and pd.status = 1
where pd.emp_id is null
```

I don't have a 3.23 instance to test with, but this should work.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google suggests that subqueries were brought in in MySql 4.1. So they're not supported in 3.23.

Thy something along these lines instead:

```
SELECT emp_id,first_name
FROM emp_master
JOIN passport_details ON emp_id
WHERE status = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1.) Subqueries were added in MySQL 4.1 [SubQuery in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/subqueries.html)

You can rewrite your query into `JOIN` statement like this.

```
SELECT a.emp_id,
       a.first_name
FROM emp_master a 
        LEFT JOIN passport_details b
           on a.emp_id = b.emp_id
WHERE a.`Status` = 1 AND
      b.emp_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Inner join will not work. He wants emp_master records that **do not** have a corresponding passport_details record.

Answer (score 0):

No, subqueries are not supported until 4.1: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-nutshell.html