# MYSQL 3.23.49 - DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ANOTHER TABLE

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-delete

I'm trying to execute the following request, on a server using MySQL 3.23.49:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table2)
```

I get the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table2'

Is there anyway to perform this request with MySQL 3.23.49 ?
I tried to look at some stored procedures, but I'm not good enough to write one working.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322484/mysql-subquery-mysql-3-23 - Subqueries were added in 4.1 so you need to rewrite the query.

Comment: How old is MySQL 3.2? Latest is 5.7, I believe. Can you upgrade? I suspect you should...

Comment: That version is at least 15 years old.  No subqueries.  No stored procedures.  No multiple-table DELETE.

Comment: @juergen d - If you are going to say it is a dup, please point to the answer.